# Replacing each character in a string with a "-" that is displayed to the user

Tags: ruby, string, for-loop

Here I'm trying to figure out how to take a word from the user and place a "-" for each character in the word. I'm trying to accomplish this with a loop but my best attempt pictured below returns a syntax error.

```
def get_display(word)
  x = 0
  loop do 
    x += 1
    break if x == word.length
    puts "-"
end
get_display("the")
```

Comment: When your question involves an exception having been raised, you should always state exactly what it was and where it occurred.  You might say something like, "The following exception was raised when the line  `"cats".giraffe` was executed: `NoMethodError: undefined method `giraffe' for "cats":String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to accomplish this with a loop but my best attempt pictured below returns a syntax error

You are missing an `end` for your `loop do`:

```
def get_display(word)
    x = 0
    loop do 
        x += 1
        break if x == word.length
        puts "-"
    end # this was missing
end
get_display("the")
```

As [you can see](http://ideone.com/hHY2qx), with that fix, it works just fine.

---

But what you probably want is this:

```
def get_display(word)
    word.length.times { puts "-" }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`String#*`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-2A):

```
word = "the"
"-" * word.length
# => "---"
"-\n" * word.length
# => "-\n-\n-\n"
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to `puts "-"` repeated `word.length` times like in the original code.